# unwanted ghost data appearing on firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Im creating firestore doc on a nested collection, so to create doc need to put some data on the doc. I am putting different data but appearing something else that is constant accross device and emulator. Why this is happening? What the doc says about it and what should remove this?

code:

```
//userPlace is the firestore doc path.
userPlace.set({ "Hi" to "Hello" }).addOnSuccessListener {
                    userPlace.collection("what").document("what").set("docData")
                }
```

this code results in data that says `arity : 0` in the userPlace doc path.

[image]

Comment: Is `userPlace` still defined as `val userPath = db.collection("Users").document(who)
    .collection("UsersActivity").document("history").set(docData)`?

Comment: The path does not matter. I got same result even for `db.collection("Users").document("history").set({ "Hi" to "Hello" })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write data to Firestore, you have two options available. The first one would be to create a custom class:

```
data class Chat(
    var message: String? = null
)
```

And to write a message to the database, you should use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
CollectionReference chatsRef = rootRef.collection("chats")
DocumentReference chatIdRef = chatsRef.document("someChatId")
chatIdRef.set(Chat("Hello"))
```

This code will produce this schema:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- chats (collection)
       |
       --- someChatId (document)
            |
            --- message: "Hello"
```

The second option that you have is to use a Map:

```
chatIdRef.set(mapOf("message" to "Hello"))
```

This code will produce the **same** schema as above.

However, if you only pass the following block of code to the `set()` method:

```
 .set({ "Hi" to "Hello" })
```

Firestore doesn't recognize that as an object of a particular class, nor a Map. In this case, the Firestore adds a field called `arity` that holds a number with the default value of `0`.

Furthermore, the above code can be also written as:

```
.set( "Hi" to "Hello" ) //Without curly braces
```

That will produce a different Firestore schema:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- chats (collection)
       |
       --- someChatId (document)
            |
            --- first: "Hi"
            |
            --- second: "Hello"
```

Now, to avoid all these kinds of situations, you should definitely use the first or second option, according to your needs, to write consistent data to Firestore.